# Installation of specific PHP version

Tags: php, repository, source

I don't know if it is just me or anyone else came across this issue? I want to install PHP 7.1.14, so I've installed the REMI repository on my CentOS 7 and enabled the php71 repository. However, when I do a `yum list php --showduplicates` it shows me only the latest and one slightly older version. Do not tell me please that my only option is to install from source because that will be a pain in the *ss because then I have to build all the php modules from source as well and that is not an option. Is there another repository that contains all the sub-versions of a specific version like 7.1 ?

Answer (score 2):

> it shows me only the latest and one slightly older version

Indeed, I only keep 2 versions in the online repository, so as today, 7.1.25 and 7.1.26 (yes, disk space have some value, especially on mirrors)

Older versions are insecure, but still available in an [archive](http://rpms.remirepo.net/store/php/common/7.1.14/) directory, but not installable using the yum/dnf command

Especially, as PHP 7.1 is now in [security mode](http://php.net/supported-versions.php) I don't see any benefit to keep an 1 year old minor version.

Using the [dedicated forum](https://forum.remirepo.net/) is a better place to ask about "remi" repository.

Comment: The reason was that I have a very complex custom extension from my dev team and now we are unable to install some applications. so we have to start trying to compile is again which is gonna take days, while we have hours now to be ready. :/ It is a bit shame you are unable to keep all the sub versions in the repository to give the people the choice if they want to be secure or not.

Comment: As I said, all the old versions are available. But need to be manually installed, also to discourage their usage.

Comment: and BTW, I don't understand you argument about "custom extension", as PHP API is stable between patch version (else, it is a bug)

Comment: "It is a bit shame you are unable to keep all the sub versions": are you ok to pay for the hosting cost ?

Comment: At least give me an estimated monthly cost, we might find a solution for you ;)